# Does a child class automatically implement parent class's interface

Tags: php, oop

This is porbably a basic OOP question but I'm not certain about the answer, and couldn't find something useful in Google search (i.e. the first page, of course)

If I have a class that is the child of another class which implements an interface, does my child class automatically become an implementation of the interface, or do I have to specifically say it to be? So

```
interface HtmlElementInterface {
    public function getName();
}

abstract class HtmlElement implements HtmlElementInterface {
    protected $_name;

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->_name = $name;
    }
    public function getName() {
        return $this->_name;
    }
    abstract public function __toString();
}

class TextInput extends HtmlElement {
    public function __toString() {
        return "<input type='input' name='{$this->_name}' id='{$this->_name}' />\n";
    }
}
```

in the case above, I don't have to tell `TextInput` to `implement HtmlElementInterface`, do I?

Comment: There is a simple way to check: put an object of type `TextInput` where PHP expects an object that implements `HtmlElementInterface` and see if it complains (it won't) and if the code runs as expected (it will).

Comment: @axiac, I like your comment. 'learning by practice' ;) Thanks

Comment: ... or check the output of the code: `$input = new TextInput('name'); var_dump($input instanceof HtmlElementInterface);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you haven't. That was implicitly an `HtmlElementInterface` implementation.

Answer (score 6):

Nope, `TextInput`  is an `HTMLElement` which is an `HtmlElementInterface`

Comment: +1 thanks! @anolsi also answered at the exact time as you, and he has fewer points so I'm marking theirs to be the answer :)